# Zoo Visitor Multiple Member Groups

Tags: zoo-visitor, zoo

I want to setup a zoo visitor form where users can select which member type (member group) they want to be part of. I've setup as described in the [documentation](http://ee-zoo.com/docs/visitor/tags/registration.html#choosing-membergroup-during-registration)
setting the allowed member groups (5|8) and the select input.

However, when I test it and activate the account, it always sets them to member group 5, despite selecting 8?

Comment: Do you set a default value for that input on the Zoo Visitor form? before you submit a test form, use your developer tools to make sure the value of that input is definitely set to "8". Report back after checking, and I'll check a site I have that has Zoo Visitor.

Answer (score 0):

I was being a complete and utter doughnut.

I was using `group_id="5|8"` in the registration form tag instead of `allowed_groups="5|8"`

Now working perfectly!